# How to remove single occurrence of an element from array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jdbc

I have a table (attributes) as defined

Id, type, value, tokenIds, contract, count, createdAt, updatedAt.

Here: tokenIds is text array and contains comma seperated non-unique ids. i.e: 1,2,3,3,4,4,5.

Its quite straightforward to add more ids in, but in a scenario i have to revert this operation.

Allow me to walk you through a scenario.

```
NEW = {1, 5, 0x01, headscarf, blue ribbon, {1}, , 1}
NEW = {1, 5, 0x01, headscarf, red ribbon, {2,3}, 2}
NEW = {1, 5, 0x01, headscarf, blue ribbon, {1,1,2}, 2} is REVERTED

REVERT = {1, 5, 0x01, headscarf, blue ribbon, {1}, 1}
```

I want to delete a list of items from stored array in db in a way that it only deletes only one occurrence of it.

(I tried my best to explain)

I tried ‘array_remove’ it removes all the occurrences, I tried some other methods but they are preventing duplication.

Data set: `[1,2,3,3,2,3,4,2,6]`
If i want to remove (2,3)
It remove just one occurrence. So, expected output is:
`[1,2,3,3,4,2,6]`

Answer (score 0):

A first attempt:

```
select
string_to_array(
  regexp_replace(
    array_to_string(
     array[1,2,3,3,2,3,4,2,6], ','), 
  '2,3,', ''
   ), 
',')::integer[];

 string_to_array 
-----------------
 {1,3,2,3,4,2,6}
```

Comment: Won't work though if the elements to be removed are at the end of the array.